# To find the real function name from DebugDiag memleak report

Tags: visual-c++, windbg, debug-symbols, debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

i have memory leak that is being analyzed using the DebugDiag tool 2.0  and the report points to "Top 5 Functions by Allocation count" and "Top 5 functions by Allocation size"  both pointing to the following function,
**MyModule!SomeClassName::Operator=+10f564**

my objective is to know the real function from the above cryptic code , in fact the class does not have any implementation of an overload operator = or =+

i have Opened the Dump in WinDbg, configured the symbols and Source file.
can anyone point me to any command that will help me to jump to the line of source or function identified in the DebugDiag report.

```
lm output
start    end        module name
5f270000 5f539000   MyModule   (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Program Files\MYCompany\MyModule.dll
    Image name: MyModule.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Tue Apr  4 18:41:49 2017 (58E39B95)
    CheckSum:         002C6CC6
    ImageSize:        002C9000
```

Comment: +10f564 tells you that it is *not* operator=(), that offset is far too high.  You must provide the tool with better PDB files so it knows what your code looks like.

Comment: Please provide evidence that fixing the symbols worked. The output of `lm` should show *private symbols* for your module if it worked correctly. As Hans suggested, the high offset is an indicator that the symbols are not correct

Comment: In the DebugDiag 2.0, i configured the symbols path correctly which also has the map files, but no luck. the function name is still not traceable.  i know the modules base address and given the offset , is there any command that i can try from Windbg, please note i am using both Windbg and DebugDiag

Comment: Then, please, post the output of `lm`